# Laravel/PHP add keys to values

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, key

I have an array like so:

```
[5, 2, 9]
```

However, I need this array:

```
[0 => 5, 1 => 2, 2 => 9]
```

So I need the index as key. Is there a function to achieve this? Now I create an empty array manually and I use array_push through a foreach loop. It works, however this doesn't seem elegant.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = [5, 2, 9];

print_r($array);
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 9
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you print  array in loop you can see default key

```
$arr=[5, 2, 9];
foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
  echo 'Key='.$key.','.'val='.$val.'<br/>';
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Key=0,val=5
Key=1,val=2
Key=2,val=9
```

Also if you echo using key like

```
$arr=[5, 2, 9];

echo $arr[1];
```

output

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php),

At first, create an array of values,

```
  $values = array(5, 2, 9);
```

Now, create an array of keys,

```
  $keys = array(0, 1, 2);
```

After that, Combine two array to get result,

```
  $result = array_combine ( array $keys , array $values );
```

Comment: Sorry, was a typo in my question. It should be 0 1 2

Comment: @BrentThierens This will work for your case, since you already have two arrays. So, just combine two arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Your array already has the keys based off its position in the array

```
$test = [5, 2, 9];


print_r($test);

Array ( [0] => 5 [1] => 2 [3] => 9 ) 

echo $test[0]; = 5
echo $test[1]; = 2
echo $test[3]; = 9
```

Comment: Exactly, arrays already have indexes like 0,1,2. For custom case we have insert indexes.